# Prevent click event from triggering other click elements undernethe the front element

Tags: angular, angular7

consider the following structure

```
<div (click)="setThing(null)">

   <table>
       <tr *ngFor="let item of items"  (click)="setThing(item)">
            <td>{{item.whatever}}</td>
            <td>{{item.whocares}}</td>
       </tr>
   </table>


  <div id="slidein" *ngIf="activeThing">
       {{ activeThing.whatver }}
  </div>
</div>
```

The idea here is that users should be able to click a table row to set an `activeThing` through a function call. 
While an `activeThing` is evaluating to true, it shows this slide in hover from the right (think like a  hamburger menu slide in)

The issue here is that the click event on the row defintiely triggers, but then the click event seems to seep through and also click the background too, which is setting `activeThing` to null.

How do I prevent the click through?

or rather, whats the better approach to this scenario.  In this situation the user is supposed to still be able to interact with other things while this pop over is visible, so I can't just have a 100%x100% faded background clickable hover. Though this way this thing behaves I'm not convinced even doing that would help

Answer (score 5):

Based on your current scenario, its appropriate to call `$event.stopPropagation();` inside the click event. What it does is.

> The stopPropagation() method of the Event interface prevents further
>   propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases.

So, the click of the parent element will not be triggered. Below is a working example.

<kbd>**Stack Blitz Demo**</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

You can prevent the click event from reaching the underlying elements by calling [Event.stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation):

```
(click)="setThing(item); $event.stopPropagation()"
```

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest most reusable way is to create a directive which stops the propagation of the click event:

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[stop-propagation]'
})
export class StopPropagationDirective {

  constructor() { }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event']) onClick($event: Event) {
    $event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  }

}
```

And then attach this directive to your activeThing:

```
<div (click)="setThing(null)">

   <table>
       <tr *ngFor="let item of items" stop-propagation (click)="setThing(item)">
            <td>{{item.whatever}}</td>
            <td>{{item.whocares}}</td>
       </tr>
   </table>


  <div id="slidein" *ngIf="activeThing">
       {{ activeThing.whatver }}
  </div>
</div>
```